# Is there a framework to easily implement server-client or master-slave inter-devcie communication apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, bluetooth, p2p

I want to make a utility app which communicates with other clients running on other devices.

One app becomes the master and waits for slaves. It connects with the slaves and sends them lightweight data in real time. The devices are within 10 meters range of eachother and it is not intended for long distance communication so bluetooth would be ok. Low latency and time synchronisation is very important.

I think GameKit peer to peer would be an option for this? What other options are there? Is there a open source framework that makes this very easy to set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert but Bluetooth- Wi-fi -  Bonjour   would be your options I guess. GameKit would be the best option to use.

***From Matthijs Hollemans:***
`GKSession has a method called sendDataToAllPeers:withDataMode:error:` *that will send the contents of an NSData object to all connected peers. You can use this method to send a single message from the server to all the clients. The message in this case is an NSData object, and what is inside this NSData object is completely up to you.*

For peer to peer connection;
*A packet is at least 10 bytes. These 10 bytes are called the “header,” and any (optional) bytes that may follow are the “payload.” Different types of packets have different payloads, but they all have the same header structure*

You can check this blueetooth game tutorial 
[Matthijs Hollemans: Snap](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12910/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-3)